# vbscript reading Cisco switch interfaces

Tags: regex, vbscript, cisco

Trying to create a script that will send a 'sh run | b interface' to a Cisco switch.  Write the output to an array.  Split that array with a vbcr so each line of the config is in a sep elemant of the array.

I have tried to skin the cat many ways and still I am struggling.

Logic in English:
Send command to Cisco device
Capture the output to an array
define expected lines 'This are lines that are required under each 'interface' of the switch
Match the 'interface' name and corresponding number and write it to a file.
Check under that interface for the specific lines in the expected
If it finds it, write the line & ", YES"
If it does not find it, write the line & ", NO"
Keep doing this until you do not find any more '^interface\s[FG][a-z].+'

Output should look like this:
Interface GigabitEthernet 0/2
 spanning-tree portfast, YES

This is the sample code that is failing:

```
'These are the expected line (not being compared in the script below but is my intention to have it compare the matched elements)
Dim vExpectedINT(4)
vExpectedINT(0)  = "spanning-tree portfast"
vExpectedINT(1)  = "switchport access vlan 17"
vExpectedINT(2)  = "switchport mode access"
vExpectedINT(3)  = "ip mtu 1400"    


'objStream.Write "######################################################### " & vbcrlf
'objStream.Write "#                  I N T E R F A C E                    # " & vbcrlf
'objStream.Write "######################################################### " & vbcrlf


nCount = 0
vConfigLines = Split(strResultsINT, vbcr)

Set re = new RegExp
re.Global = False
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Multiline = False
re.Pattern = "^interface [FG]"

' Regex Ex Definition
Set re2 = new RegExp
re2.Global = False
re2.IgnoreCase = True
re2.Multiline = False
re2.Pattern = "\sspanning-tree\sportfast"

' Regex Ex Definition
Set re3 = new RegExp
re3.Global = False
re3.IgnoreCase = True
re3.Multiline = False
re3.Pattern = "ip\smtu\s1400"

Set re4 = new RegExp
re4.Global = False
re4.IgnoreCase = True
re4.Multiline = False
re4.Pattern = "!"

' Compares the information
x = 1
Do While x <= Ubound(vConfigLines) - 1 do 
    MsgBox chr(34) & strLine & chr(34)
    If re.Test(vConfigLines(x)) Then
        ' Write data to not expected section
        x=x+1
        do
            If ! re4.Test(vConfigLines(x)) Then
                MsgBox vConfigLines(x)
                'objStream.Write vConfigLines(x) & vbcr
                elseif re2.Test(vConfigLines(x)) Then
                MsgBox vConfigLines(x)
                elseif re3.Test(vConfigLines(x)) Then
                MsgBox vConfigLines(x)
            else
                exit do
            end if
            x=x+1
        loop
        end IF
   End If
Loop
```

This is a sample of the vConfigLines output:

There could be 48+ port per switch.

```
interface FastEthernet1/0/1
 switchport access vlan 127
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 210
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 srr-queue bandwidth shape 0 3 0 0
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust cos
 auto qos voip trust 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/2
 switchport access vlan 127
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 210
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 srr-queue bandwidth shape 0 3 0 0
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust cos
 auto qos voip trust 
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface FastEthernet1/0/3
 switchport access vlan 127
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 210
 srr-queue bandwidth share 10 10 60 20
 srr-queue bandwidth shape 0 3 0 0
 priority-queue out 
 mls qos trust cos
 auto qos voip trust 
 spanning-tree portfast
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When facing a difficult and complex task, just follow these rules:

```
Divide the task in independently solvable subproblems
  getting the info from Cisco
  processing the resulting file
    gather interesting info
    output

Concentrate on the difficult subtask(s)
  processing the resulting file

Solve a simplified but generalized version of (each) subtask using handmade data
for easy testing
  You have items and are interested in whether they (don't) have given properties
```

Data to play with:

```
Item 0 (both props)
 prop_a
 prop_b
!
Item 1 (just b)
 prop_b
!
Item 2 (a only)
 prop_a
!
Item 3 (none)
!
Item 4 (irrelevant prop)
 prop_c
!
Item 5 (Richy)
 prop_c
 prop_b
 prop_a
!
Item 6 (Junky)
 junk

 prop_b
 whatever

!
#Item 7 (Nasty)
# prop_a_like_but_not_prop_a
# prop_b
#!

Keep it simple
  don't do more than absolutely necessary
  don't use variables/components you can do without
```

So let's start:

You have to deal with a text file (lines). So don't do more than

```
  Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\TheProblem.txt")
  Dim sLine
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
      sLine = Trim(tsIn.ReadLine())
      If "" <> sLine Then
      End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
```

90 % of the code using Split on .ReadAll is just fat. Yes, it's `Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream` and not `Do While tsIn.AtEndOfStream = False`. No `Set tsIn = Nothing`,
please.

The data is organized in blocks (Item n ... !), so make sure you
recognize the parts and know what to do when finding them:

```
  Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\TheProblem.txt")
  Dim sItem  : sItem    = "Item"
  Dim sEnd   : sEnd     = "!"
  Dim sLine
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
      sLine = Trim(tsIn.ReadLine())
      If "" <> sLine Then
         Select Case True
           Case 1 = Instr(sLine, sItem)
             WScript.Echo "Begin, note item (name)"
           Case 1 = Instr(sLine, sEnd)
             WScript.Echo "End, output info"
             WScript.Echo "----------"
           Case Else
             WScript.Echo "Middle, gather info"
         End Select
      End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
```

output:

```
Begin, note item (name)
Middle, gather info
Middle, gather info
End, output info
----------
Begin, note item (name)
Middle, gather info
End, output info
----------
...
```

For each item the output should be:

```
name, property, yes|no
```

The easiest way to do that is

```
WScript.Echo Join(aData, ", ")
```

Joining beats concatenation, especially if you want to set/manipulate the
parts independently and/or to pre-set some of them in the beginning.

```
  Dim aData  : aData    = Array( _
      Array( "Item?", "prop_a", "NO") _
    , Array( "Item?", "prop_b", "NO") _
  )
  Dim sLine, aTmp, nIdx
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
      sLine = Trim(tsIn.ReadLine())
      If "" <> sLine Then
         Select Case True
           Case 1 = Instr(sLine, sItem)
             aTmp = aData
             For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
                 aTmp(nIdx)(0) = sLine
             Next
           Case 1 = Instr(sLine, sEnd)
             For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
                 WScript.Echo Join(aTmp(nIdx), ", ")
             Next
             WScript.Echo "----------"
           Case Else
             WScript.Echo "Middle, gather info"
         End Select
      End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
```

The output

```
...
Item 3 (none), prop_a, NO
Item 3 (none), prop_b, NO
...
```

shows that by setting sensible defaults (NO), this version of the script
deals correctly with items having none of the interesting properties.

So lets tackle the middle/Case Else part:

```
   Case Else
     For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
         If 1 = Instr(sLine, aTmp(nIdx)(1)) Then
            aTmp(nIdx)(2) = "YES"
            Exit For
         End If
     Next
```

output now:

```
Item 0 (both props), prop_a, YES
Item 0 (both props), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 1 (just b), prop_a, NO
Item 1 (just b), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 2 (a only), prop_a, YES
Item 2 (a only), prop_b, NO
----------
Item 3 (none), prop_a, NO
Item 3 (none), prop_b, NO
----------
Item 4 (irrelevant prop), prop_a, NO
Item 4 (irrelevant prop), prop_b, NO
----------
Item 5 (Richy), prop_a, YES
Item 5 (Richy), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 6 (Junky), prop_a, NO
Item 6 (Junky), prop_b, YES
----------
```

But what about Nasty:

```
#Item 7 (Nasty)
# prop_a_like_but_not_prop_a
# prop_b
#!
```

The simple Instr() will fail, if one property name is a prefix of
another. To prove that starting simple and add complexity later
is good strategy:

```
  Dim sFSpec : sFSpec   = "..\data\TheProblem.txt"
  WScript.Echo goFS.OpenTextFile(sFSpec).ReadAll
  Dim tsIn   : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile(sFSpec)
  Dim sItem  : sItem    = "Item"
  Dim sEnd   : sEnd     = "!"
  Dim aData  : aData    = Array( _
      Array( "Item?", "prop_a", "NO") _
    , Array( "Item?", "prop_b", "NO") _
  )
  Dim aRe    : aRe      = Array(New RegExp, New RegExp)
  Dim nIdx
  For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aRe)
      aRe(nIdx).Pattern = "^" & aData(nIdx)(1) & "$"
  Next
  Dim sLine, aTmp
  Do Until tsIn.AtEndOfStream
      sLine = Trim(tsIn.ReadLine())
      If "" <> sLine Then
         Select Case True
           Case 1 = Instr(sLine, sItem)
             aTmp = aData
             For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
                 aTmp(nIdx)(0) = sLine
             Next
           Case 1 = Instr(sLine, sEnd)
             For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
                 WScript.Echo Join(aTmp(nIdx), ", ")
             Next
             WScript.Echo "----------"
           Case Else
             For nIdx = 0 To UBound(aTmp)
                 If aRe(nIdx).Test(sLine) Then
                    aTmp(nIdx)(2) = "YES"
                    Exit For
                 End If
             Next
         End Select
      End If
  Loop
  tsIn.Close
```

output:

```
Item 0 (both props)
 prop_a
 prop_b
!
Item 1 (just b)
 prop_b
!
Item 2 (a only)
 prop_a
!
Item 3 (none)
!
Item 4 (irrelevant prop)
 prop_c
!
Item 5 (Richy)
 prop_c
 prop_b
 prop_a
!
Item 6 (Junky)
 junk

 prop_b
 whatever

!
Item 7 (Nasty)
 prop_a_like_but_not_prop_a
 prop_b
!

Item 0 (both props), prop_a, YES
Item 0 (both props), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 1 (just b), prop_a, NO
Item 1 (just b), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 2 (a only), prop_a, YES
Item 2 (a only), prop_b, NO
----------
Item 3 (none), prop_a, NO
Item 3 (none), prop_b, NO
----------
Item 4 (irrelevant prop), prop_a, NO
Item 4 (irrelevant prop), prop_b, NO
----------
Item 5 (Richy), prop_a, YES
Item 5 (Richy), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 6 (Junky), prop_a, NO
Item 6 (Junky), prop_b, YES
----------
Item 7 (Nasty), prop_a, NO
Item 7 (Nasty), prop_b, YES
----------
```